# How to read a .dat file from bottom to top in fortran?

Tags: file, fortran, gfortran

I'm new to fortran and am trying to change the following A.dat file to the desired B.dat and overwrite it (B.dat) on A.dat (i.e. I want to read A.dat's rows from bottom to top and overwrite it (e.g. in this example, I want to replace the first row with the third (last) one and vice versa )). Can anyone show me how to do that in fortran 90?

```
    A.dat's contents       B.dat's contents (desired)

    111001                 1111
    110110                 110110
      1111                 111001
```

So far, by @High Performance Mark's help, I tried the following:

```
program test
    real, dimension(:), allocatable :: x
    Integer (kind=8) :: n
    integer(kind = 4) :: i
    open (unit=99, file='A.dat', access='sequential', form='formatted')
    open(unit=20, file='B.dat', access='sequential', form='formatted')
    do i=3,1,-1
        read(99,*) n
        write(*,*) n
        write(20, *) n
    end do
    close(20)
end program test
```

But I stuck in the section "write a new file "in reverse order"" (aforementioned program just reads A.dat contents and writes them in the terminal and B.dat file with the same order). How should I do that?

> P.S. Machine info:
>
> ---
>
> "Linux 3.16.6-200.fc20.x86_64 (fedora 20)"
>
> ---
>
> "gcc version 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-7) (GCC)"
>
> ---
>
> "using .f90"

Comment: Better than show you, let me tell you the futility of your proposal.  To read the bottom line first you'll first have to read the file from the top to the bottom.  Now, technically it is possible to work your way backwards through the file but it is fiddly in the extreme, especially so if, as your snippet suggests, the lines (or records) in the file are not all of the same lengths.  Don't bother, read the file from top to bottom, write a new file in reverse order.  Not only much simpler, it will also be much faster.

Comment: Read the file, store its contents in memory, write them out in reverse order –  High Performance Mark

Comment: @High Performance Mark, again thanks for your help and sorry for the weakness of my question from experts' point of view, It's simply because of this fact that I'm new to fortran and will do my best to get better :)

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this in Fortran will demonstrate why its not something you want to do in Fortran.

```
program futility
    implicit none
    call execute_command_line('tac A.dat > B.dat')
end program
```

Comment: Just like that?! :D @casey thank you so much for your time and answer.

Comment: @RoliJ Yes, and the point is that you can run `tac A.dat >B.dat ` in a shell script. You don't need Fortran and this Fortran doesn't do anything but run that command. To actually do the logic in Fortran would be a lot more work.

Comment: Oh, I see. So this a shell script which terminal understands it by default (I forgot what `execute_command_line` means) and writing it in fortran will be an attempt for writing the whole `tac file1.dat > file2.dat` command line. Again thanks for your help and sorry for the weakness of my question from experts' point of view, It's simply because of this fact that I'm new to fortran and will do my best to get better :)

Comment: sorry that I cannot vote up for your useful answer. I have not the required reputation to do so. Again thanks :)